# Implementation of merge sort using threads and fork

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, fork, mergesort

**Problem:** I'm trying to implement Merge Sort in the following way, I have a Parent and two children. the first child will use the merge sort on his own, the second child will implement this the following way: create 2 threads, first one will sort the first half of the array, the second one will sort the rest. Then, after calling the merge sort, he will create again 2 threads for the first half, and 2 threads for the rest, and so on, until we end up in the base case and we finish. In the end, I want to check how much faster the second child implemented the merge sort than the first child.

**My question:** I've created 2 childs, the first child is implementing the sort merge and everything is fine. the second child - I was able to create only 2 threads, instead of much more (then 2 for each half, and so on), and in the end it neither prints the array nor the date of its finish.

**This is the code for the second child:**

```
if((id2 = fork()) == 0 && id1 != 0)
    {
        printf("Child2: \n");
        ans1 = pthread_create ( &thread1 , NULL , mergeSort ,(arr3, (arr_size / 2) - 1 ,arr_size - 1 )) ;
        ans2 = pthread_create ( &thread2 , NULL , mergeSort ,(arr3, 0, (arr_size / 2)-  1 )) ;
        ans3 = pthread_create ( &thread3 , NULL , printArray ,(arr3, arr_size) ) ;
        execl("/bin/date", "date",0);
        if ( ans1 != 0 || ans2 != 0 || ans3 != 0) {
            printf ( " \n can't create threads " ) ;
            exit(0) ;
        }
            pthread_join ( thread1 , NULL ) ;
            pthread_join ( thread2 , NULL ) ;
            pthread_join ( thread3 , NULL ) ;

    }
```

**I'm using UNIX, and for compiling:**

```
gcc -lpthread prog.c
```

**for executing:**

```
./a.out
```

This is the whole code:

```
/* C program for Merge Sort */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 100

// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
       are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
       are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
   sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    int min = -1000, max = 1000;
    int arr[10], arr2[10], arr3[10];
    int i,r;
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int id1,id2;
    //Threads init
    pthread_t thread1 , thread2, thread3;
    int ans1, ans2, ans3;


    for( i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
        r = rand() % (max - min + 1);
        arr[i] = r;
        arr2[i] = r;
        arr3[i] = r;
    }
    //printf("Before: \n");

    if((id1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Child1: \n");
        mergeSort(arr2, 0, arr_size - 1);
        printArray(arr2, arr_size);
        execl("/bin/date", "date",0);
    }

    if((id2 = fork()) == 0 && id1 != 0)
    {
        printf("Child2: \n");
        ans1 = pthread_create ( &thread1 , NULL , mergeSort ,(arr3, (arr_size / 2) - 1 ,arr_size - 1 )) ;
        ans2 = pthread_create ( &thread2 , NULL , mergeSort ,(arr3, 0, (arr_size / 2)-  1 )) ;
        ans3 = pthread_create ( &thread3 , NULL , printArray ,(arr3, arr_size) ) ;
        execl("/bin/date", "date",0);
        if ( ans1 != 0 || ans2 != 0 || ans3 != 0) {
            printf ( " \n can't create threads " ) ;
            exit(0) ;
        }
            pthread_join ( thread1 , NULL ) ;
            pthread_join ( thread2 , NULL ) ;
            pthread_join ( thread3 , NULL ) ;

    }
    wait();
    if(id1 != 0 && id2 != 0){

        printf("Given array is \n");
        printArray(arr, arr_size);
        printf("Father:\n");
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
        printArray(arr, arr_size);
        execl("/bin/date", "date",0);
        printf("\nSorted array is \n");
        //printf("After: \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDITED CODE:

```
   /* C program for Merge Sort */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100

// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
       are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
       are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
   sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

void* mergeSort2(void* args)
{

    int* newArgs = (int*)args;
    int l = newArgs[1];
    int r = newArgs[2];

    pthread_t thread1 , thread2;
    int ans1, ans2;

    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = (r+l)/2;
        int newArgs1[3] = {newArgs[0], l, m};
        int newArgs2[3] = {newArgs[0], m+1, r};
        ans1 = pthread_create ( &thread1 , NULL , mergeSort2 ,(void*)newArgs1);
        ans1 = pthread_create ( &thread2 , NULL , mergeSort2 ,(void*)newArgs2);
        pthread_join(thread1,NULL);     
        pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

        merge(newArgs[0], l, m, r);

    }

}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

static void print_timestamp(void)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *utc = gmtime(&now);
    char iso8601[32];
    strftime(iso8601, sizeof(iso8601), "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S", utc);
    printf("%s\n", iso8601);
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    int min = -1000, max = 1000;
    int arr[10], arr2[10], arr3[10];
    int i,r;
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int id1,id2;
    int args[3] ={arr3, 0, arr_size - 1};
     struct timeval tvalBefore, tvalAfter;
     struct timeval tvalBefore1, tvalAfter1;
    //Threads init
    pthread_t thread1;
    int ans1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for( i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
        r = rand() % (max - min + 1);
        arr[i] = r;
        arr2[i] = r;
        arr3[i] = r;
    }
    //printf("Before: \n");

    if((id1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
     gettimeofday (&tvalBefore, NULL);
    //Operation to do
        printf("Child1: \n");
        mergeSort(arr2, 0, arr_size - 1);
        printArray(arr2, arr_size);
        print_timestamp();
    gettimeofday (&tvalAfter, NULL);

    // Changed format to long int (%ld), changed time calculation

    printf("Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 1: %ld microseconds\n",
            ((tvalAfter.tv_sec - tvalBefore.tv_sec)*1000000L
           +tvalAfter.tv_usec) - tvalBefore.tv_usec
          ); // Added semicolon
    }

    else if((id2 = fork()) == 0)
    {

        printf("Child2: \n");
        //Start Timer
        gettimeofday (&tvalBefore1, NULL);
        //Operation to do
        ans1 = pthread_create ( &thread1 , NULL , mergeSort2 ,(void*)args);
        pthread_join ( thread1 , NULL ) ;

        print_timestamp();
        gettimeofday (&tvalAfter1, NULL);
        // Changed format to long int (%ld), changed time calculation

         printf("Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 2: %ld microseconds\n",
            ((tvalAfter1.tv_sec - tvalBefore1.tv_sec)*1000000L
           +tvalAfter1.tv_usec) - tvalBefore1.tv_usec
          ); // Added semicolon
    }

    else{
        wait();
        wait();
         gettimeofday (&tvalBefore, NULL);
        //Operation to do
        printf("Given array is \n");
        printArray(arr, arr_size);
        printf("Father:\n");
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
        printArray(arr, arr_size);
        print_timestamp();

        gettimeofday (&tvalAfter, NULL);

    // Changed format to long int (%ld), changed time calculation

    printf("Time in microseconds for sorting Father: %ld microseconds\n",
            ((tvalAfter.tv_sec - tvalBefore.tv_sec)*1000000L
           +tvalAfter.tv_usec) - tvalBefore.tv_usec
          ); // Added semicolon
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, threads and processes are traditionally un-gendered. Anyway, why are you replacing your whole child process with `date` before the threads have finished? That `execl` call should _replace_ the whole process with `date`, which will then exit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Edited :)

Comment: @Useless Even if I put the date code after the third 'pthread_join' it still won't work.

Comment: You also (try to) run the print array in parallel to the mergeSort threads - it shouldn't run until after they're both complete (in which case you can just `join` them both and then run `printArray` synchronously)

Comment: Your `mergeSort` function doesn't _try_ to create more threads, did you want it to? It just calls itself recursively, which is the normal single-threaded way.

Comment: Why do you need to fork at all? Just create two copies of the data, create two child threads that start operating on one copy just as you describe and let the main thread sort the other copy. Much less hassling around. You can then maintain four timestamps, first is set when you start your child threads, second when last child thread terminates, third when main thread starts sorting, fourth when main thread is done. Then compare the timestamp differences...

Comment: @Useless I see, then I should create 'MergeSort-new' function, and in that function to create 2 threads. so everytime is calls it recursively it creates 2 threads that will continue doing the job. I'm not quite sure how to implement it. And also, if I try to put the printf code of printing the array after the pthread_joins, it still won't print anything. Is there a way to determine the threads have finished?

Comment: Additionally: additionally: if one child thread terminates, just let it create *one* further child - the parent can restart with the next half as if it was the second child.

Comment: About performance: Do not expect the threaded solution being faster... First, creating new threads requires quite some overhead. To cover this, you need huge data to see any benefits at all. But with your algorithm, you need a huge number of threads then, too, so huge number of overhead, and additionally, most of these threads will be inactive anyway as no more threads can be active at the same time than you have CPU cores in your system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Program stops because of calls to `execl()`

You have:

```
    …
    ans3 = pthread_create ( &thread3 , NULL , printArray ,(arr3, arr_size) ) ;
    execl("/bin/date", "date",0);
    if ( ans1 != 0 || ans2 != 0 || ans3 != 0) {
        …
```

The `execl()` replaces your process and all its threads with `date`, which produces its output and exits.  You can't time-stamp your work like that!

You probably need to call `time()` or a higher-resolution timing mechanism, and then `localtime()` or `gmtime()` to create a broken-down time, and then `strftime()` to format it as you want, and finally `printf()` or similar to print the result.  That all belongs in a function, of course, not in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static void print_timestamp(void)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *utc = gmtime(&now);
    char iso8601[32];
    strftime(iso8601, sizeof(iso8601), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", utc);
    printf("%s\n", iso8601);
}
```

Where you have `execl()`, call `print_timestamp()` instead.

Or, more simply, use `system()` instead of `execl()`:

```
system("/bin/date");
```

This is a grotesquely heavyweight way of reporting the time, but it has the merit of simplicity.

#### Sub-second resolution times

> I need to determine the time in milliseconds.

It depends on your platform, but on POSIX-ish systems you can use [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) or [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) to get sub-second timing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static void print_timestamp(void)   // UTC to seconds
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *utc = gmtime(&now);
    char iso8601[32];
    strftime(iso8601, sizeof(iso8601), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", utc);
    printf("%s\n", iso8601);
}

static void print_utc_ms(void)      // UTC to milliseconds
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    struct tm *utc = gmtime(&tv.tv_sec);
    char iso8601[32];
    strftime(iso8601, sizeof(iso8601), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", utc);
    printf("%s.%.3d\n", iso8601, tv.tv_usec / 1000);
}

static void print_local_us(void)    // Local time to microseconds
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);     // CLOCK_MONOTONIC has merits too
    struct tm *lmt = localtime(&ts.tv_sec);
    char iso8601[32];
    strftime(iso8601, sizeof(iso8601), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", lmt);
    printf("%s.%.6ld\n", iso8601, ts.tv_nsec / 1000L);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_timestamp();
    print_utc_ms();
    print_local_us();
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
2017-05-05T16:04:14
2017-05-05T16:04:14.268
2017-05-05T09:04:14.268975
```

NB: Once you've fixed your code so it isn't using `execl()`, there may still be other problems to resolve — there probably are other problems to fix.  But fixing this is a key step to getting your threads to run to completion.

#### Creating working code

Taking the revised code from the question, applying basic 'cleanliness' to it (making sure it compiles cleanly under stringent warning options), the program seems to work.  The 'array of `int`' approach to passing a pointer and two `int` values doesn't work on a 64-bit system, so I created a `struct Sort` to contain the information.  I also moved the 'start clock' and 'stop clock' calls to `gettimeofday()` closer to the code being measured (no printing in the calling code in the way).  I added headers needed on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (GCC 7.1.0).  The code also prints the input data before it sorts any of it.  The cleanup work was basically 'around' the sort code; the core sorting algorithms were not changed at all.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>   // gettimeofday()
#include <unistd.h>     // fork()
#include <sys/wait.h>   // wait()

#define N 100

struct Sort
{
    int *data;
    int  lo;
    int  hi;
};

// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
static
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
       are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
       are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
   sub-array of arr to be sorted */
static
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

static
void *mergeSort2(void *args)
{
    struct Sort *newargs = args;
    int *data = newargs->data;
    int l = newargs->lo;
    int r = newargs->hi;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int ans1, ans2;

    if (l < r)
    {
        int m = (r + l) / 2;
        struct Sort newArgs1 = {data, l, m};
        struct Sort newArgs2 = {data, m + 1, r};
        ans1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, mergeSort2, &newArgs1);
        ans2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, mergeSort2, &newArgs2);
        if (ans1 != 0 || ans2 != 0)
            exit(1);
        pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

        merge(data, l, m, r);
    }
    return 0;
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
static
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

static void print_timestamp(void)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *utc = gmtime(&now);
    char iso8601[32];
    strftime(iso8601, sizeof(iso8601), "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S", utc);
    printf("%s\n", iso8601);
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main(void)
{
    int min = -1000, max = 1000;
    int arr[10], arr2[10], arr3[10];
    int i, r;
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int id1, id2;
    struct Sort args = { arr3, 0, arr_size - 1};
    struct timeval tvalBefore, tvalAfter;
    struct timeval tvalBefore1, tvalAfter1;
    // Threads init
    pthread_t thread1;
    int ans1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        r = rand() % (max - min + 1);
        arr[i] = r;
        arr2[i] = r;
        arr3[i] = r;
    }
    printf("Given array is \n");
    printArray(arr, arr_size);
    fflush(stdout);

    if ((id1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Child1: \n");
        gettimeofday(&tvalBefore, NULL);
        mergeSort(arr2, 0, arr_size - 1);
        gettimeofday(&tvalAfter, NULL);
        printArray(arr2, arr_size);
        print_timestamp();

        printf("Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 1: %ld microseconds\n",
               ((tvalAfter.tv_sec - tvalBefore.tv_sec) * 1000000L
                + tvalAfter.tv_usec) - tvalBefore.tv_usec);
    }
    else if ((id2 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Child2: \n");
        gettimeofday(&tvalBefore1, NULL);
        ans1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, mergeSort2, &args);
        if (ans1 == 0)
            pthread_join( thread1, NULL );
        gettimeofday(&tvalAfter1, NULL);
        print_timestamp();
        printArray(arr3, arr_size);
        printf("Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 2: %ld microseconds\n",
               ((tvalAfter1.tv_sec - tvalBefore1.tv_sec) * 1000000L
                + tvalAfter1.tv_usec) - tvalBefore1.tv_usec);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(0);
        wait(0);
        printf("Parent:\n");
        gettimeofday(&tvalBefore, NULL);
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
        gettimeofday(&tvalAfter, NULL);
        printArray(arr, arr_size);
        print_timestamp();

        printf("Time in microseconds for sorting Parent: %ld microseconds\n",
               ((tvalAfter.tv_sec - tvalBefore.tv_sec) * 1000000L
                + tvalAfter.tv_usec) - tvalBefore.tv_usec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (source in `ms83.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition ms83.c -o ms83
$
```

Example run 1:

```
Given array is 
574 494 441 870 1121 800 1864 1819 889 242 
Child1: 
242 441 494 574 800 870 889 1121 1819 1864 
2017-05-05  21:31:23
Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 1: 10 microseconds
Child2: 
2017-05-05  21:31:23
242 441 494 574 800 870 889 1121 1819 1864 
Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 2: 3260 microseconds
Parent:
242 441 494 574 800 870 889 1121 1819 1864 
2017-05-05  21:31:23
Time in microseconds for sorting Parent: 7 microseconds
```

Example run 2:

```
Given array is 
150 562 748 1685 889 1859 1807 1904 863 1675 
Child1: 
150 562 748 863 889 1675 1685 1807 1859 1904 
2017-05-05  21:31:40
Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 1: 11 microseconds
Child2: 
2017-05-05  21:31:40
150 562 748 863 889 1675 1685 1807 1859 1904 
Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 2: 4745 microseconds
Parent:
150 562 748 863 889 1675 1685 1807 1859 1904 
2017-05-05  21:31:40
Time in microseconds for sorting Parent: 7 microseconds
```

Note that the threading solution is three orders of magnitude slower than the non-threading code.

When I tried increasing the array size from 10 to 10,000, the threaded child did not complete.  That means thread creation failed somewhere.  The error reporting is defective (I was being lazy).  Switching to 500 entries yielded:

```
Given array is 
1984 1436 713 1349 855 1296 559 1647 567 1153 1156 1395 865 1380 840 1253 714 1396 333 404 538 1468 1381 489 1274 34 697 1484 1742 756 1221 1717 331 532 746 842 1235 1179 1185 1547 1372 1305 138 404 76 762 605 61 1242 1075 1896 203 1173 844 1582 1356 1044 1760 1635 1833 1595 1651 1892 1842 1508 727 357 221 878 967 1665 1783 1927 1655 1110 220 711 371 1785 401 188 1132 1947 1214 5 1414 1065 730 826 807 1155 654 1745 1993 1215 741 1721 1509 604 16 139 804 1773 690 1673 861 1657 566 969 1891 1718 1801 200 1817 235 711 372 319 507 483 1332 968 1138 246 1082 1074 1569 1774 488 358 1713 350 583 381 418 300 1011 416 563 748 1858 837 1678 1336 1516 1177 1449 1664 1991 1465 1159 1653 1724 311 1360 902 1182 1768 1471 1606 1813 1925 825 122 1647 1790 1575 323 153 33 1825 1343 1183 1707 1724 1839 1190 1936 442 1370 206 1530 1142 561 952 478 25 1666 382 1092 418 720 1864 652 313 1878 1268 993 1446 1881 893 1416 319 577 1147 688 1155 726 1336 1354 1419 217 1236 213 1715 101 946 1450 135 297 1962 1405 455 924 26 569 755 64 1459 1636 395 1417 138 924 1360 893 1216 1231 1546 1104 252 697 1602 1794 1565 1945 1738 941 1813 1829 714 280 369 1861 1466 1195 1284 1936 78 1988 145 1541 1927 833 135 913 1214 405 23 1107 390 242 309 964 1311 724 284 342 1550 1394 759 1860 28 1369 1417 362 747 1732 26 1791 646 1817 1392 666 762 1297 945 507 58 928 1972 811 170 1660 1811 1969 573 242 1297 74 581 1513 1258 1311 547 627 942 1965 945 343 1633 197 843 249 77 320 611 1674 303 1346 148 533 1800 259 916 1498 1058 365 973 451 1143 1121 1033 126 595 726 1232 894 1584 878 1076 1796 257 531 144 740 1033 630 471 919 773 1276 1523 1195 475 667 40 91 1336 350 1650 970 1712 542 1927 168 1107 917 1271 649 1006 1428 20 1341 1283 774 1781 1427 1342 316 1317 1162 1333 991 1288 1853 1917 210 1589 1744 1942 962 557 1444 396 1330 378 625 1776 179 434 290 870 961 1365 226 605 1842 1629 1421 1883 108 102 1068 671 1086 692 1053 45 660 1746 1351 399 1308 833 42 1219 491 248 503 499 3 1965 1043 1452 604 1736 1974 675 14 1491 1757 1116 1520 1540 983 108 15 1030 742 1535 423 1802 1622 1401 1801 167 824 230 404 1722 814 1222 1626 1177 1772 1645 27 1061 1848 1031 1659 1725 1862 959 362 728 1644 957 934 1160 1862 915 995 1201 119 1191 259 963 1889 
Child1: 
3 5 14 15 16 20 23 25 26 26 27 28 33 34 40 42 45 58 61 64 74 76 77 78 91 101 102 108 108 119 122 126 135 135 138 138 139 144 145 148 153 167 168 170 179 188 197 200 203 206 210 213 217 220 221 226 230 235 242 242 246 248 249 252 257 259 259 280 284 290 297 300 303 309 311 313 316 319 319 320 323 331 333 342 343 350 350 357 358 362 362 365 369 371 372 378 381 382 390 395 396 399 401 404 404 404 405 416 418 418 423 434 442 451 455 471 475 478 483 488 489 491 499 503 507 507 531 532 533 538 542 547 557 559 561 563 566 567 569 573 577 581 583 595 604 604 605 605 611 625 627 630 646 649 652 654 660 666 667 671 675 688 690 692 697 697 711 711 713 714 714 720 724 726 726 727 728 730 740 741 742 746 747 748 755 756 759 762 762 773 774 804 807 811 814 824 825 826 833 833 837 840 842 843 844 855 861 865 870 878 878 893 893 894 902 913 915 916 917 919 924 924 928 934 941 942 945 945 946 952 957 959 961 962 963 964 967 968 969 970 973 983 991 993 995 1006 1011 1030 1031 1033 1033 1043 1044 1053 1058 1061 1065 1068 1074 1075 1076 1082 1086 1092 1104 1107 1107 1110 1116 1121 1132 1138 1142 1143 1147 1153 1155 1155 1156 1159 1160 1162 1173 1177 1177 1179 1182 1183 1185 1190 1191 1195 1195 1201 1214 1214 1215 1216 1219 1221 1222 1231 1232 1235 1236 1242 1253 1258 1268 1271 1274 1276 1283 1284 1288 1296 1297 1297 1305 1308 1311 1311 1317 1330 1332 1333 1336 1336 1336 1341 1342 1343 1346 1349 1351 1354 1356 1360 1360 1365 1369 1370 1372 1380 1381 1392 1394 1395 1396 1401 1405 1414 1416 1417 1417 1419 1421 1427 1428 1436 1444 1446 1449 1450 1452 1459 1465 1466 1468 1471 1484 1491 1498 1508 1509 1513 1516 1520 1523 1530 1535 1540 1541 1546 1547 1550 1565 1569 1575 1582 1584 1589 1595 1602 1606 1622 1626 1629 1633 1635 1636 1644 1645 1647 1647 1650 1651 1653 1655 1657 1659 1660 1664 1665 1666 1673 1674 1678 1707 1712 1713 1715 1717 1718 1721 1722 1724 1724 1725 1732 1736 1738 1742 1744 1745 1746 1757 1760 1768 1772 1773 1774 1776 1781 1783 1785 1790 1791 1794 1796 1800 1801 1801 1802 1811 1813 1813 1817 1817 1825 1829 1833 1839 1842 1842 1848 1853 1858 1860 1861 1862 1862 1864 1878 1881 1883 1889 1891 1892 1896 1917 1925 1927 1927 1927 1936 1936 1942 1945 1947 1962 1965 1965 1969 1972 1974 1984 1988 1991 1993 
2017-05-05  21:43:11
Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 1: 62 microseconds
Child2: 
2017-05-05  21:43:11
3 5 14 15 16 20 23 25 26 26 27 28 33 34 40 42 45 58 61 64 74 76 77 78 91 101 102 108 108 119 122 126 135 135 138 138 139 144 145 148 153 167 168 170 179 188 197 200 203 206 210 213 217 220 221 226 230 235 242 242 246 248 249 252 257 259 259 280 284 290 297 300 303 309 311 313 316 319 319 320 323 331 333 342 343 350 350 357 358 362 362 365 369 371 372 378 381 382 390 395 396 399 401 404 404 404 405 416 418 418 423 434 442 451 455 471 475 478 483 488 489 491 499 503 507 507 531 532 533 538 542 547 557 559 561 563 566 567 569 573 577 581 583 595 604 604 605 605 611 625 627 630 646 649 652 654 660 666 667 671 675 688 690 692 697 697 711 711 713 714 714 720 724 726 726 727 728 730 740 741 742 746 747 748 755 756 759 762 762 773 774 804 807 811 814 824 825 826 833 833 837 840 842 843 844 855 861 865 870 878 878 893 893 894 902 913 915 916 917 919 924 924 928 934 941 942 945 945 946 952 957 959 961 962 963 964 967 968 969 970 973 983 991 993 995 1006 1011 1030 1031 1033 1033 1043 1044 1053 1058 1061 1065 1068 1074 1075 1076 1082 1086 1092 1104 1107 1107 1110 1116 1121 1132 1138 1142 1143 1147 1153 1155 1155 1156 1159 1160 1162 1173 1177 1177 1179 1182 1183 1185 1190 1191 1195 1195 1201 1214 1214 1215 1216 1219 1221 1222 1231 1232 1235 1236 1242 1253 1258 1268 1271 1274 1276 1283 1284 1288 1296 1297 1297 1305 1308 1311 1311 1317 1330 1332 1333 1336 1336 1336 1341 1342 1343 1346 1349 1351 1354 1356 1360 1360 1365 1369 1370 1372 1380 1381 1392 1394 1395 1396 1401 1405 1414 1416 1417 1417 1419 1421 1427 1428 1436 1444 1446 1449 1450 1452 1459 1465 1466 1468 1471 1484 1491 1498 1508 1509 1513 1516 1520 1523 1530 1535 1540 1541 1546 1547 1550 1565 1569 1575 1582 1584 1589 1595 1602 1606 1622 1626 1629 1633 1635 1636 1644 1645 1647 1647 1650 1651 1653 1655 1657 1659 1660 1664 1665 1666 1673 1674 1678 1707 1712 1713 1715 1717 1718 1721 1722 1724 1724 1725 1732 1736 1738 1742 1744 1745 1746 1757 1760 1768 1772 1773 1774 1776 1781 1783 1785 1790 1791 1794 1796 1800 1801 1801 1802 1811 1813 1813 1817 1817 1825 1829 1833 1839 1842 1842 1848 1853 1858 1860 1861 1862 1862 1864 1878 1881 1883 1889 1891 1892 1896 1917 1925 1927 1927 1927 1936 1936 1942 1945 1947 1962 1965 1965 1969 1972 1974 1984 1988 1991 1993 
Time in microseconds for sorting CHILD 2: 83377 microseconds
Parent:
3 5 14 15 16 20 23 25 26 26 27 28 33 34 40 42 45 58 61 64 74 76 77 78 91 101 102 108 108 119 122 126 135 135 138 138 139 144 145 148 153 167 168 170 179 188 197 200 203 206 210 213 217 220 221 226 230 235 242 242 246 248 249 252 257 259 259 280 284 290 297 300 303 309 311 313 316 319 319 320 323 331 333 342 343 350 350 357 358 362 362 365 369 371 372 378 381 382 390 395 396 399 401 404 404 404 405 416 418 418 423 434 442 451 455 471 475 478 483 488 489 491 499 503 507 507 531 532 533 538 542 547 557 559 561 563 566 567 569 573 577 581 583 595 604 604 605 605 611 625 627 630 646 649 652 654 660 666 667 671 675 688 690 692 697 697 711 711 713 714 714 720 724 726 726 727 728 730 740 741 742 746 747 748 755 756 759 762 762 773 774 804 807 811 814 824 825 826 833 833 837 840 842 843 844 855 861 865 870 878 878 893 893 894 902 913 915 916 917 919 924 924 928 934 941 942 945 945 946 952 957 959 961 962 963 964 967 968 969 970 973 983 991 993 995 1006 1011 1030 1031 1033 1033 1043 1044 1053 1058 1061 1065 1068 1074 1075 1076 1082 1086 1092 1104 1107 1107 1110 1116 1121 1132 1138 1142 1143 1147 1153 1155 1155 1156 1159 1160 1162 1173 1177 1177 1179 1182 1183 1185 1190 1191 1195 1195 1201 1214 1214 1215 1216 1219 1221 1222 1231 1232 1235 1236 1242 1253 1258 1268 1271 1274 1276 1283 1284 1288 1296 1297 1297 1305 1308 1311 1311 1317 1330 1332 1333 1336 1336 1336 1341 1342 1343 1346 1349 1351 1354 1356 1360 1360 1365 1369 1370 1372 1380 1381 1392 1394 1395 1396 1401 1405 1414 1416 1417 1417 1419 1421 1427 1428 1436 1444 1446 1449 1450 1452 1459 1465 1466 1468 1471 1484 1491 1498 1508 1509 1513 1516 1520 1523 1530 1535 1540 1541 1546 1547 1550 1565 1569 1575 1582 1584 1589 1595 1602 1606 1622 1626 1629 1633 1635 1636 1644 1645 1647 1647 1650 1651 1653 1655 1657 1659 1660 1664 1665 1666 1673 1674 1678 1707 1712 1713 1715 1717 1718 1721 1722 1724 1724 1725 1732 1736 1738 1742 1744 1745 1746 1757 1760 1768 1772 1773 1774 1776 1781 1783 1785 1790 1791 1794 1796 1800 1801 1801 1802 1811 1813 1813 1817 1817 1825 1829 1833 1839 1842 1842 1848 1853 1858 1860 1861 1862 1862 1864 1878 1881 1883 1889 1891 1892 1896 1917 1925 1927 1927 1927 1936 1936 1942 1945 1947 1962 1965 1965 1969 1972 1974 1984 1988 1991 1993 
2017-05-05  21:43:11
Time in microseconds for sorting Parent: 51 microseconds
```

Different runs showed dramatic variations in the processing time for child 2. I observed the values: 83,377; 73,929; 78,977; 83,977; 94,159; 81,526 microseconds.

You might get some  benefit from threading with large data sets sorted by a small number of threads (say 10,000 rows of data, but only 8 threads, each sorting 1250 rows of data), but probably not even then.  As you increase the number of threads beyond the number of cores on the system, you get less and less benefit from the multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! It is still won't help though. I need to determine the time in milliseconds.

Comment: Oh?  Well running `date` won't help then — it reports in seconds at most.

Comment: Yes. I'm using struct timeval, and the function gettimeofday to implement it. Works well. now the last thing is implementing the Child 2 with threads..

Comment: I've edited the code, it is still not working, I believe there a little work to do to finish that.

Comment: I've tried to compile the revised code. It doesn't get anywhere close to passing my basic cleanliness test. I use `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wold-style-definition       ms83.c -o ms83` to compile the file `ms83.c`, and run into many problems. One bug is that you create two threads but pass `&thread1` both times, and then try to join `thread2` — which wasn't initialized. Basically, in my view, it isn't really worth trying to review the code for bugs until it is clean enough to compile with those flags. I allow some slack, but not much.

Comment: On a Mac, and according to POSIX, you need `#include <sys/time.h>` to get a declaration of `gettimeofday()`.  Also, thread functions need to return a `void *` (not `void`); change the signature of `mergeSort2()` and add `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: Changed &thread1 to &thread2, and mergeSort2() returns void* now. It still doesn't solve the problem though. I still have somewhere problems in doing the sortMerge.

Comment: I also fixed a little problem, int newArgs2[3] = {newArgs[0], m+1, r}; instead of int newArgs2[3] = {newArgs[0], m, r}; but still it won't output the Child2. I'll update soon again *sad face*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143535/discussion-between-ilan-aizelman-ws-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan! I've no words to describe my appreciation!

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

1. as noted in comments and Jonathan's answer, you call `exec` and replace your whole process image before your threads complete (and possibly before they actually start, since they may not have been given their first timeslice yet)
2. if you move that, you still have the problem that your `printArray` function was run *in parallel* to your sort threads, instead of afterwards
3. if you fix that, you still have the problem that your `printArray` thread was started improperly (with a likely invalid input pointer), for the same reason as for the sorting threads, described in more detail below
4. if you fix the printing, your sorting thread invocation is completely wrong (much detail follows below)
5. if you fix the thread invocation, your code still doesn't do what you claim you wanted: to keep starting new child threads for smaller and smaller sub-ranges of your input array

Let's start with the prototype of `pthread_create`, the declaration of your thread function, and the thread creation call:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

this requires a function of shape `void* start_routine(void *)` as its third argument. However, you have

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) { ... }
```

which will *nevertheless be called* with only the first argument having a defined value. I'm amazed your compiler didn't warn about this.

Now, consider your the fourth argument to `pthread_create` in the following call:

```
    ans1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,
                          mergeSort,
                          (arr3, (arr_size / 2) - 1 ,arr_size - 1 )) ;
```

it takes the expression `(arr3, (arr_size / 2) - 1 ,arr_size - 1 )`. However, C doesn't have tuple types, and even if it did they wouldn't be convertible to `void*`. Instead this uses the comma operator `,` to *discard* the results of the first two expressions, and so you're actually using the integer value of `arr_size - 1` as a pointer argument.

I'd expect it to crash when it tries to start the child thread - you didn't say how your program failed, but a SEGV would be common. You can catch these in a debugger, but it'll be somewhere inside the pthread library code, so it might not help much.

A sane solution for your problem would look something like this un-tested and never-compiled sample code:

```
/* use this for the fourth argument to pthread_create */
struct Range {
  int *array;
  int left;
  int right;
  pthread_t thread;
};

void mergeSortRange(Range *r) {
  const int width = (right - left);
  const int mid = left + (width/2);
  if (width > THRESHOLD) {
    /* wide enough to be worth a child thread */
    Range left = { r->array, r->left, mid };
    Range right = { r->array, mid+1, r->right };
    pthread_create(&left.thread, NULL,
                   mergeSortRangeThreadFunction,
                   &left);
    mergeSortRange(&right);
    pthread_join(left.thread);
    mergeSortedHalved(r->array, r->left, mid, r->right);
  } else {
    regularSingleThreadedMergeSort(r->array, r->left, r->right);
  }
}

/* this is what you pass to pthread_create */
void* mergeSortRangeThreadFunction(void *data) {
  Range *r = (Range *)data;
  mergeSortRange(r);
  return data;
}
```

although, even with `THRESHOLD` set to something good, it's better to use a thread pool than to start & stop threads repeatedly.

Finally, of course, you don't need to use recursion to start these threads and populate these `Range` structures - you could just create an array of `size/THRESHOLD + 1` range descriptors, create one thread per core, and then figure out some logic for deciding when you're allowed to merge two consecutive ranges.

Comment: Thanks Useless! I'm still working on it, I will update as soon as I finish.

Comment: I've edited the code, it is still not working, I believe there a little work to do to finish that.